# Insert new line after each "<div>"

Tags: python, html, styles

I have a document full of html divs, i want to style it. I want a programm that inserts a new line after each  element.

I would prefer handling this in python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We are not here to write code for you. Read this and edit your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a script that searches for those elements in file, and adds 
 tag after them.

Something like this:

```
with open('asdf.html') as file:
   line = file.read()
   if '</div>' in line:
      file.write('<br>')
```